# Popup keep getting closed in all mobile phone When ever I focus any form field to type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, popup

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is my code....

```
jQuery("#open-pop").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var topPos = parseInt(jQuery(window).scrollTop());
        jQuery(".product-details .cta-wrapper .product-cta").addClass("own-pop-area");
        jQuery(".product-details .cta-wrapper .product-cta").appendTo("body");
        //jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").css("display","block");
        jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").parent().parent().css({"position":"absolute","top":(topPos+10)+"px","left":"0px","z-index":"999"});
        jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").fadeIn(500,function(){

            jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").parent().parent().css({"position":"absolute","top":(topPos+10)+"px","left":"0px","z-index":"999"});
        });

        jQuery("#my-over").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px","left":"0px","z-index":"99","width":"100%","height":"100%","background-color":"black","opacity":"0.5"});
        jQuery("#my-over").fadeIn(500);

        jQuery("#close-pop").css("display","inline-block");
        jQuery("#open-pop").css("display","none");

        return false;




        });


jQuery("#close-pop").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        //alert("dddd");
        jQuery(".own-pop-area").prependTo(".product-details .cta-wrapper");
        //jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").css("display","none");
        jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").fadeOut(500,function(){

            jQuery(".add-to-cart .form-view-main").parent().parent().removeAttr("style");
            jQuery("#close-pop").css("display","none");

            jQuery("#open-pop").css("display","block");

        });
        jQuery("#my-over").fadeOut(500);

        return false;
        });
```

Please please please some one help me out... I have even tried bootstrap modal popup... but it is the same case...

here is the link to the site where you can find the button...

https://www.honeymoon.style/africa/botswana/belmond-eagle-island-lodge